# ssh connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, ip

I am not able to connet to any remote server. It shows up this error.
I am able to ping the same ip address.

Also I checked sshd is running :

**sudo service sshd status**

ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-02-11 10:35:22 IST; 47min ago
 Main PID: 2610 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─2610 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Also the port is active & listening :

**netstat -lnp | grep 22**

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22969    1268/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-gnLG2rgPez

I checked firewall also :

**sudo ufw status**

Status: active
 
To Action From -- ------ ---- 
22 ALLOW Anywhere
 
3000 ALLOW Anywhere 
OpenSSH ALLOW Anywhere 
22 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
3000 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6) 
OpenSSH (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)

Then I tried disabling firewell also. It did not work.

I am able to SSH localhost as below :

**ssh 192.168.1.11**

daizy@192.168.1.11's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
- Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
- Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

21 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sun Feb 11 11:00:36 2018 from 192.168.1.11

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 & I am trying to connect to a Digital Ocean Server. It worked properly before 8th Feb. 
I did not change any SSH configuration.

If I try on another port :

**ssh -p 80 root@139.59.2.129**
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

**ssh -vvv  139.59.2.129** 

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "139.59.2.129" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 139.59.2.129 [139.59.2.129] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 139.59.2.129 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 139.59.2.129 port 22: Connection refused

I could also easily login to localhost using:
**ssh -vvv localhost**

Comment: Try to `nc -vz <ip> 22` from your local machine to verify nothing is blocking the port in between (like a firewall).

Comment: it shows upnc: connect to 139.59.2.129 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

Comment: There you have it then. Do you have a firewall running anywhere in between?

Comment: sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: I have checked firewall also, tested above

Comment: Your initial question lacks details about your network for anyone to be able to help you further as is. You could try to disable your firewall and test. There might be some router/NAT happening in between which could also be causing it.

Comment: I tried disabling firewall also and tried. But its still shows connection refused. May i know what details are required about the network. So that problem can be  traced

Comment: Did you try if you can SSH localhost on the server? If you can do that it is definitely a network issue. You should update the initial question with all your findings from these comments and make use of the code blocks to make it readable. Add details about if the server is directly connected to the internet or if there is any NAT going on. The server responds on port 80 (I tried) so maybe you can copy any configuration you have on port 80 to port 22. Add which OS and version you're using, what firewall software, if you changed any SSH configuration, if it has ever worked etc.

Comment: please provide output from `ssh -vvv <ip>` #replace <ip> with the server you want to ssh to and `ssh -vvv localhost` thanks

Comment: I have put the output in the question section. Please check